# SharePoint 2013 Link JS within Master Page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to add jquery's js file to my master page (seattle.master). I cannot get any suggestions from the internet to work- each suggestion seems to come with replies of "that doesn't work- try this instead- that doesn't work" type of loop.

Here is the type of thing I've been trying-
...After the initial script links in the master file...

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID=”ScriptLink1″ runat=”server” Defer=”False” Name=”~site/SiteAssets/Javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js”></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

This gives me a blank page of death. Any ideas.

Comment: Do you modify the file `seattle.master` directly, rather than the file `seattle.html`?

Comment: Please refer to this link for the correct steps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305168/how-to-add-jquery-to-masterpage-2013

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
1) create solution
2) add code as per link http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2013/10/02/how-to-deploy-javascript-to-master-page-through-solution/
3) deploy solution