# How to add Jquery to MasterPage 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to add jQuery to sharepoint 2013 master page. What I did:

1)

- Copy jquery - "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"  to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS.
- Copy seattle.html and add `<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/_layouts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />-->`
- Upload seattle.html as ASP NET MASTERPAGE
- Publish it ---> Nothing happend. To seattle.master wasn't appear Sharepoint:Scriptlink

2)

- Copy jquery - "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" to SiteAssets. My application is on root site collection so for instance access to jquery is

`http://localhost/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`

- Copy seattle.html

  - Add `!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="'~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />-->`
  - Still no effect

What is the correct way from begining to the add of adding Jquery to Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you forgot to apply custom master page, go to Master Page settings page and set `Site Master Page` and  `System Master Page` to your custom master page.

> Note: there is a typo in the second option: name attribute contains
>   `'` symbol

### How to reference JavaScript file in SharePoint 2013 master page

Assume the following scenario:

- a custom master page `helsinki.master` with associated HTML file are
  used
- jQuery library `jquery.min.js` is  located in SharePoint `Site Assets` library

Then, in order to reference jQuery library in custom master page the following steps are used:

- Open an associated HTML file `helsinki.html`
- Insert the line `<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript"
  name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"  runat="server"
  Localizable="false"/>-->`
- Publish `helsinki.html`
- Go to Master Page settings page and set `Site Master Page` and
  `System Master Page` to `helsinki.master`

**About System Master Page**

System Master Page is used by administrative pages, lists, and document library views on this site

> This approach has been tested in SharePoint 2013 and works for me.

Comment: i tried this one and its not working
` name="/sites/sample/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" `

What should i change?

Comment: Works for SharePoint online too! :D

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest to add jQuery with a custom DelegateControl. With this approach there is no need to modify the MasterPage. 
Every Masterpage contains a placeholder where you are able to hook in custom scripts, like jQuery.

Here is a detailed description how to develop the solution:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx

The cool thing with the delegateControl is, that you can use any scopes for this Solution. So you can apply jQuery to the whole Farm, Webapplication, Sitecollection or Web.

Regards